# Direct sum of Kernels of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Prove that $\text{Ker}(ϕ−id)⨁\text{Ker}(ϕ+id)=V$. If $\phi^2 = id$

I only know that, $x∈\text{Ker}(ϕ−id) \iff  ϕ(x)=x$.

Comment: Can you please include your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Nehorai I think it useful to prove $Ker(\phi + id) = Im(\phi - id)$

Comment: What about $\phi = 2id$?

Comment: @user251257 then $\phi(x) \neq x$

Comment: @MaryFisher no. Then the sum is zero, as both kernels are trivial. What does the $=V$ part means?

Comment: @MaryFisher This is not true for any $\phi:V\to V$, so we need the definition of your $\phi$ and possibly $V$, or any special property they're supposed to satisfy.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I've edited the post

Comment: hint: $0=\phi^2 - id = (\phi - id)(\phi + id)$

Comment: @user251257 it's trivial. I don't know what to do afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write $x=\frac12(\phi(x)+x)+\frac12(\phi(x)-x)$, and check $\phi(x)\pm x\in\ker(\phi\mp\operatorname{Id})$. This proves $V=\ker(\phi+\operatorname{Id})+\ker(\phi-\operatorname{Id})$.

Then suppose $x\in\ker(\phi+\operatorname{Id})\cap\ker(\phi-\operatorname{Id})$: the above decomposition shows $x=0$.Hence the sum is a direct sum.

*Note:*

This results from a more general result, known as the *kernels decomposition lemma*: let $P=P_1P_2\dots P_r$ a decomposition of the polynomial $P $ as a product of *coprime* polynomials and $\phi$ an endomorphism of a vector space $V$. Then $$\ker P(\phi)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^r\ker P_i(\phi).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f = \phi - id$ and $g = \phi + id$.

1. We have $V = \ker(f) \oplus f(V)$ and $f(V) \subseteq \ker(g)$. So $V = \ker(f) + \ker(g)$.
2. For $x\in \ker(f) \cap \ker(g)$ we have $x = \phi(x) = -x$. Thus $x=0$ and the sum is direct.

Comment: why $f(V) ⊆ ker(g)$